# Take pictures/video with my goPro from the command line

Tags: command-line, usb, webcam, gopro

I'm looking for a way to capture pictures or video from my **entry-level** GoPro using the **command line** and with the camera connected **via USB**. There're lots tutorials of how to do it with the goPros that have Wi-Fi. Is there any way to do it like we do with webcams?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I don't care, whatever it works. I usually use Mac OS X and CentOS. I would prefer linux in general so I can use it on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: It would be great if there would be a feedback about the downvotes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @carlosvega What is the model of GoPro you have???

Comment: Thanks. As I said in the question, is the entry-level GoPro. http://es.shop.gopro.com/EMEA/cameras/hero/CHDHA-301-EU.html

Comment: Is your camera detected by linux eg. is it mounted on something like /dev/video0? If so, I can show you examples on how to do it fairly easily using gstreamer or mencoder.

Comment: How can I determine if/where it is mounted? Here is the result of mount -l:

Comment: /dev/sda6 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755,size=1024)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)

Comment: tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,noexec,nodev,none,name=systemd)

Answer (score 1):

None of the GoPros support live streaming via USB. USB is primarily used for charging camera and access SD card. You simply cannot live stream from entry-level GoPro.

Comment: any source supporting that?

Comment: Well, I used to work at GoPro. I've never seen a document supporting video stream over USB.